# Changed SqlDataSource updatecommand to stored procedure and now the update link does nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I had a working gridview and sqldatasource with select and updatecommand.  I then changed the commandtype to a stored procedure (and commandname obviously), with some more robust logic in the sproc.

It works when I run it from a SQL window but now when I edit a gridview row, the update link does nothing.  I can hit edit and cancel just fine but update is dead.  No error, no action, nothing.  Here's my old datasource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlThresholdsProjected" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:tmus_bill %>" 
    SelectCommand="sp_BillingThresholdsGet" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE DiscountTiers SET Discount = @Discount, Min = @Min, Max = @Max WHERE DiscountTiersID = @DiscountTiersID">
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlYear" DbType="Decimal" Name="year" />
  </SelectParameters>
  <UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Min" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Max" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Discount" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="DiscountTiersID" />
  </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And the new SqlDataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlThresholdsProjected" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:tmus_bill %>" 
    SelectCommand="sp_BillingThresholdsGet" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    UpdateCommand="spu_FeeThresholds" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" DataSourceMode="DataReader">
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlYear" DbType="Decimal" Name="year" />
  </SelectParameters>
  <UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Min" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Max" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Discount" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="DiscountTiersID" />
  </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The gridview:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="udpThresholds">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvThresholdsProjected" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      DataKeyNames="DiscountTiersID" DataSourceID="sqlThresholdsProjected" AllowSorting="false" 
      EditRowStyle-BackColor="GreenYellow" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
      <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" />
      <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DiscountTiersID" HeaderText="DiscountTiersID" 
          InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Min" HeaderText="Min" DataFormatString="{0:C}" ControlStyle-Width="50px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Max" HeaderText="Max" DataFormatString="{0:C}" ControlStyle-Width="50px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Discount" HeaderText="Discount" DataFormatString="{0:N2}%" ControlStyle-Width="30px" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Year">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Year") %>'></asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
      </Columns>
      <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336699" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlThresholdsProjected" runat="server" 
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:tmus_bill %>" 
        SelectCommand="sp_BillingThresholdsGet" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
        UpdateCommand="spu_FeeThresholds" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" DataSourceMode="DataReader">
      <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlYear" DbType="Decimal" Name="year" />
      </SelectParameters>
      <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Min" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Max" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Discount" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DiscountTiersID" />
      </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I can't answer my own question since I'm such a newb so I'll put it here:  Thanks for responding pid.  I figured out the solution.  My datasource contained five databound controls but I was only passing 4 as parameters.  The first 2 or 50 times I debugged the code, I didn't notice the part in a popup error on an asdx page sort of buried that read in part, too many arguments specified.  Once I added the "Year" parameter to my sproc, even though I didn't need it, all is fine.  At least for now...

Thanks all who checked out the question.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to guess here. DataSourceMode must be a DataSet to get two-way databinding. The DataReader is just a "reader".